# Microsoft EDGE XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied with VueJS

Tags: vue.js, microsoft-edge

I have a website build with VueJS on front and Java on back. The website requires to be logged in to see the content.

On Firefox, IE and Chrome the login works perfect, but on Microsoft EDGE I get this error when I call the login method:

```
SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied.
```

This is the login method.

```
login() {
  axios.post('/login', this.user,
    {'headers':{'X-AUTH-TOKEN': localStorage.token}},
    {'headers':{'Content-Type': 'application/json'}})
    .then((response) => {
      AuthPlugin.getToken(response.data);
      alertify.set('notifier','delay', 3);
      alertify.success("Success! You are now logged in.");

      axios.get("/user", this.user)
      .then((response) => {
        this.$router.push('/home');
        AuthPlugin.setUser(this.user.username);
      })
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      alertify.error('Invalid User');
    });
}
```

I searched on the internet for solutions but what I tried didn't worked.

This is the [network on EDGE](http://prntscr.com/gr7r1o)

This is the [network on Chrome](http://prntscr.com/gr7tq1)

Does someone know how to fix that error?

Answer (score 1):

My first guess is that you need to enable local storage on Edge rather than it being a network problem.

Comment: Please wait until Monday to test it because the project is at work and I can't test it outside work network, even is a domain name and not on localhost. Thank you for your advise.

Comment: My friend I followed this link to enable local storage `https://support.ancestry.com/s/article/ka215000000MV57AAG/Enabling-or-Allowing-Cookies-from-Ancestry-US-1460088562626-2165` but still the same error (screen shot) `https://prnt.sc/gs6sm2`